# dotnet sonarscanner не воспринимает jre 11 и 17 на ubuntu 20.04.3 (.net 5)

Tags: java, .net, ubuntu, sonarqube

В docker развёрнут SonarQube. C ним взаимодействует эта штука https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/latest/analyzing-source-code/scanners/sonarscanner-for-dotnet/
Следующая команда даёт сбой:

> ~/project$ /usr/bin/dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="admin" /d:sonar.password="user"

> SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.2.2
> Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
> Post-processing started.
> Calling the SonarScanner CLI...
> Could not find 'java' executable in JAVA_HOME or PATH.
> The SonarScanner did not complete successfully
> 20:05:32.56  Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

Пробовал openjdk jre 11 и 17 headless пакет. Переменная JAVA_HOME устанавливалась вручную. Что не так?